# flask-CORS extension doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, cors, flask-cors

I'm developing a website using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) and [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). The server and the client are separated into two folders and in development I'm running the server using `flask run` and the client (Vuejs) using `yarn serve`.

So the frontend is coming together nicely, and I now want to start doing some calls to the server. Since the client is served on port `8080`, and the server on port `5000` I'm getting CORS errors. To avoid these I'm trying to use the [flask-cors extension](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I've copied exactly what they do in [the example](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simple-usage):

```
from flask import Flask
from app.config import Config
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
CORS(app)
```

And instead of the last line I also tried [the resource specific example](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#resource-specific-cors):

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting CORS errors in the frontend.

As far as I understand the server side should send along headers which allow cors, but I'm not actually seeing a request in the browser network tab, I just get an error in the console.

[image]

Also, it says `only the protocol schemes http [...] https` are allowed. I'm doing an ordinary http request, so I'm not sure why that wouldn't work.

And from here I'm kinda lost. Does anybody know how I can debug this?

Comment: You just need to add or `http://` to the request URL in your frontend JavaScript code. Right now you have `localhost:5000/api/waypoints/` in your frontend code. Change that to `http://localhost:5000/api/waypoints/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind. I now realise I didn't add `http://` to my request..

Thanks for listening anyway.. :-)